# Question about integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

IS $\mathbb Z_7$ an example of a commutative ring without zero-divisors that is not an integral domain?

I know it is has no zero divisors because it is prime, and that it is a field, but can someone help me understand integral domain?

Comment: No, because it has unity. The definition of an integral domain is (typically) a commutative ring with $1$ such that there are no zero divisors. In particular, *every* field is an integral domain.

Comment: So, the only thing that would make something NOT an integral domain is the fact that it has unity?

Comment: Or if there are zero divisors or if it fails to be commutative.

Comment: @t-bongers : Why give the answer in the comments ?

Comment: An integral domain is a commutative ring with $1$ and no zero divisors. Is there a part of this definition you don't understand?

Comment: @anon I understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb Z_7$ is a field, and *every field is an integral domain*.

On the other hand, every integral domain $D$ determines its *field of fractions* where fractions are formally built the same way as one constructs $\Bbb Q$ out of $\Bbb Z$.

We can also say that an integral domains $D$ contain the "integer elements" of its fraction field. 
 (And, as the example of $\Bbb Z_7$ (or, of any field) shows it is possible that all elements of a field are considered "integer" in this sense.)